# Typing a function to differentiate classes based on an attribute

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I am currently trying to add type hints for a library that exposes to the end user a function like the following (simplified for clarity):

```py
def bar(obj):
    if hasattr(obj, "foo"):
        return obj.foo()
    return obj
```

Because the `obj` parameter can be defined by the end user, I need to come-up with a generic way to convey intent and make sure that the `bar` function gives a precise type as return value:

- if the argument has an `foo` attribute that can be callable without any parameters, returns the return type of that attribute;
- else returns the type of `obj`.

---

My best try so far is the following:

```py
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar, Union, cast

T = TypeVar("T")
U = TypeVar("U", covariant=True)

class HasFoo(Protocol[U]):
    def foo(self) -> U:
        ...

def bar(obj: Union[HasFoo[U], T]) -> Union[U, T]:
    if hasattr(obj, "foo"):
        return cast(HasFoo[U], obj).foo()
    return cast(T, obj)
```

It seems to work properly for classes that don't have a `foo` attribute:

```py
from typing_extensions import assert_type

class A:
    pass

a = A()

bar_a = bar(a)
assert_type(bar_a, A)
assert bar_a == a
```

However it does not work for classes that do have the `foo` attribute (mypy errors in comments):

```py
class B:
    def foo(self) -> int:
        return 42

b = B()

bar_b = bar(b)
# ^ error: Argument 1 to "bar" has incompatible type "B"; expected "HasFoo[<nothing>]"  [arg-type]
# ^ error: Need type annotation for "bar_b"  [var-annotated]

assert_type(bar_b, int)
# ^ error: Expression is of type "Any", not "int"

assert bar_b == 42
```

The error I'm not understanding is `Argument 1 to "bar" has incompatible type "B"; expected "HasFoo[<nothing>]"  [arg-type]`.

---

The issue might be coming from the fact that for the `Union[HasFoo[U], T]` parameter, mypy does not know how to distinct one from the other.

I have noticed that if I create the following function instead, everything works as expected:

```py
from typing import Iterable


def bar2(obj: Union[HasFoo[U], Iterable[T]]) -> Iterable[Union[U, T]]:
    if hasattr(obj, "foo"):
        yield cast(HasFoo[U], obj).foo()
    else:
        yield from cast(Iterable[T], obj)


bar2_a = bar2([a])
assert_type(bar2_a, Iterable[A])
assert list(bar2_a) == [a]


bar2_b = bar2(b)
assert_type(bar2_b, Iterable[int])
assert list(bar2_b) == [42]
```

I suspect that this is because this time there is no common ground between `HasFoo[U]` and `Iterable[T]`.

---

With all that being said, how can I properly type the initial `bar` function?

*I am using python 3.10.6 and mypy 0.971*

Comment: This seems like you should be using an abstract base class that requires the `foo` method, and the argument should be a subclass of this.

Comment: @Barmar I agree that this would make typing easier, but this would require changes in the library, plus changes in all user codes that use the library (they now need to inherit from the abstract class). This is why I tried to use a Protocol.

Comment: @rogdham Have you tried using `typing.Any`, is it compatible with your use case?

Comment: With `def bar(obj: typing.Any) -> typing.Any:`, `mypy` is not going to complain. Please let me know if this works for you and I'll answer the question.

Comment: I also found an alternative solution if `typing.Any` is not suitable for your use case.

Comment: @g14u well of course using `Any` everywhere prevents mypy from complaining, but we are loosing the return type for the end user. In other words, to have strong type checking on the return value, they would have to do something like `cast(A, bar(a))` instead of just `bar(a)`. I would happily read your alternative solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `@overload` makes this relatively painless - just type the two different possibilities as two overloads, then leave the hints off the implementation.

```py
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar, overload

T = TypeVar("T")
U = TypeVar("U", covariant=True)

class HasFoo(Protocol[U]):
    def foo(self) -> U:
        ...

@overload
def bar(obj: HasFoo[U]) -> U:
    ...

@overload
def bar(obj: T) -> T:
    ...

def bar(obj):
    if hasattr(obj, "foo"):
        return obj.foo()
    return obj
```

Using `reveal_type` with your examples yields the expected results: `bar_a` is an `A` and `bar_b` is an `int`.